# Definitions of "separate points" and "$T_2$-space"

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-topology

I am confused about the following two definitions.

Let $E$ and $F$ be vector spaces over the field $\mathbb{K}$.

1. $F$ separates points of $E$ under the bilinear form $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$ if, given $e\in E$ such that $\langle e,f \rangle=0$ for all $f\in F$, then $e=0$. (or equivalently, if for each $e\neq 0$ in $E$, there exists $f\in F$ such that $\langle e,f \rangle\neq 0$)
2. $E$ is a $T_2$-space. (i.e., any two points have disjoint neighborhoods.)

---

According to the first line of the following link, it seems that 1. and 2. are equivalent. I have no idea how 1. implies 2. or 2. implies 1.   (in 1., it seems there is no concept of neighborhoods)
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeakTopology.html

Comment: What topologies do $E$ and $F$ have? If one the dual of the other?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am not sure how to answer this question.

Comment: If you want talk about $E$ being $T_2$ you need a topology. Are you studying weak topologies, maybe?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Maybe I need a topology; however, my question is if $F$ separates points of $E$, how can I say $E$ is $T_2$? As the first line in the mathworld link, it does not specify the topology of $X$; it just says that $X$ is a topological vector space.

Comment: If $F$ separates points and we give $E$ the weak topology wrt $F$ and this bilinear form, then $E$ is Hausdorff in that topology.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma And Hausdorff is $T_2$, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, given this bilinear form which separates points on $E$, we define $\sigma(E,F)$ as the weakest topology on $E$ such that all maps
$P_f: E \to K: P_f(e) = \langle e, f \rangle$ for all $f \in F$are continuous.

Then $E$ is Hausdorff: let $e_1 \neq e_2$ in $E$, then $e_1 - e_2 \neq 0$, so there is some $f \in F$ with $\langle (e_1-e_2),f\rangle \neq 0$, by the second formulation of the separating points condition.

But then $P_f(e_1 - e_2) = P_f(e_1) - P_f(e_2) \neq 0$, so $P_f(e_1) \neq P_f(e_2)$ in the field $\mathbb{K}$, which is Hausdorff (usually even metrisable) and so these points have disjoint open neighbourhoods $O_1$ resp. $O_2$ in $\mathbb{K}$.
Then $e_i \in P_f^{-1}[O_i], i=1,2$ and these sets are in $\sigma(E,F)$ and disjoint as the $O_i$ are. So $E$ is $\sigma(E,F)$-Hausdorff.

The reverse implication is similar, try it out.